# WSL2 is only returning the usage message when I try to install distros

Tags: powershell, wsl2

I am following the tutorial here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZMfHaUkhfc0 I am at about the 15:00 mark. I have installed WSL2 in the Administrator account's PowerShell. I am logged in as a regular user. I installed Docker Desktop and Ubuntu. I rebooted. Then I open Powershell again as the Administrator account and it doesn't see the Ubuntu distro I installed or the Docker Desktop I installed.

```
PS C:\windows\system32> wsl -l -v
Windows Subsystem for Linux has no installed distributions.
Distributions can be installed by visiting the Microsoft Store:
https://aka.ms/wslstore
PS C:\windows\system32> wsl.exe -d Ubuntu
There is no distribution with the supplied name.
PS C:\windows\system32> wsl.exe --install Ubuntu
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Usage: wsl.exe [Argument] [Options...] [CommandLine]

Arguments for running Linux binaries:

If no command line is provided, wsl.exe launches the default shell.

--exec, -e <CommandLine>
    Execute the specified command without using the default Linux shell.

--
    Pass the remaining command line as is.
```

Again, I am using the regular (non-Administrator) account and am able to open the Ubuntu app and the Docker Desktop app in Windows, but the Powershell session I have running as Administrator does not see either. How do I fix this? And why does the `wsl.exe --install Ubuntu` call fail with a plain usage message?

Comment: It's advisable to install distros from the Microsoft Store.

Comment: As described on the [manual page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install), the correct syntax would be `wsl --install -d <DistroName>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linux distributions installed with WSL are a per-user installation and can't be shared with other Windows user accounts (ref. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/setup/environment).
[image]
Hence, by running powershell as the Admin account you won't see distributions installed with a regular (non-admin) account. Instead, I'd expect you see them by running `wsl -l -v` with a regular-user powershell session.
Probably the command `wsl.exe --install Ubuntu`, run by an Admin powershell session, shows you the help precisely because you don't have any distribution installed with Admin account. In this case, since wsl is installed (clearly, since you must have been admin to install it), but no distribution (since you installed them with the regular user), it shows you the help (ref. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install).
[image]
You should run the command `wsl --list --online` and then `wsl --install -d <DistroName>`.

Comment: Was this answer generated by ChatGPT? You recommended a command the author indicated did not work.

Comment: Nope @Ramhound , this answer it's all of mine... but of course you may not like it and I accept it.
MrSnrub said that command `wsl -l -v` doesn't show distribution, but it's because he installed them with another user.
His command `wsl.exe --install Ubuntu` it's a bit different from mine, which has an additional -d option: `wsl.exe --install -d Ubuntu`. This because the first command make 2 things in one shot: install wsl and install default distro. But if wsl is already installed (which is the case) you should check available online distro and install them with the additional -d option.

Comment: I apologize If I've been unclear: it's the fault of my natural (un)intelligence and not the intervention of artificial intelligence :(

Comment: The only difference between your command and the author’s command is your command will set the default distribution. Furthermore, the difference between wsl -l -v and wsl --list --online is one that lists all installed distributions and the other only lists those that are online or running. I would expect greater contextual awareness out of an answer. The authors problem is answered by several existing questions with answers to WSL not listing distributions in an elevated prompt